# Are there features or functionality in JavaFX which will benefit by the language/VM improvements of later Java versions?

Tags: java, jvm, virtual-machine, javafx, backwards-compatibility

I wonder whether JavaFX will keep using the "main" JVM shipped by JavaSE and therefore receiving all improvements to the VM or if they will use their own spin-off of the Hotspot VM specially optimized for them.

Will it be possible to target JavaFX with every version of the Java language or are there limitations or backward compatibility problems?

Are there features planned for later versions of the Java language from which JavaFX could benefit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One of the [features](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/roadmap-1446331.html) planned for Java FX is "Tighter Integration with Java SE". Also, from the [JavaFX FAQ, questions 5](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#5) it is clear that JavaFX will still be using Java SE as its JVM, as it says

   > starting with JavaFX 2.0.2 and Java SE 7 Update 2 (December 2011),
   >   Oracle has started rolling out a solution through which the
   >   installation of the JavaFX Runtime when the Java SE 7 Oracle JRE is
   >   installed. Additionally, the JavaFX SDK is now part of the Java SE SDK
   >   (JDK). When Java SE 8 reaches General Availability (GA), the JavaFX
   >   Runtime will become part of the Oracle JRE
2. Java FX [1.1, 1.2](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/06/02/first-look-javafx-12) and [2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#8) have not been completely backwards compatible. And integrating JavaFX with JavaSE might mean loosing some compatibility between versions of Java SE and versions of JavaFX. Somewhat soon to tell.
3. The JavaFx Roadmap and future releases announced don't show any sort of advantages for JavaFX among the new Java SE features. Given the touted integration I would not discount this, though.

Now, all of this is based in Oracle plans at the moment. Who's to say what might change from here to the arrival of JavaFX 3?